# Why does Alice get the lake in with the kayak?

Tags: plot-explanation, friday-the-13th, friday-the-13th-1980

At the end of *Friday the 13th*, after she killed Pamela, Alice takes a canoe and enters the lake.

Why does she do it? Why she doesn't take the car with Pamela reached the camp and drive to the near city?

Comment: Shock and exhaustion?